# How can I negate a user defined Integer?

Tags: haskell

I have

```
data Weight = Fin Integer | Inf
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

negate :: Weight -> Weight
negate Inf = error "negative infinity not supported"
```

I want `negate Fin (-1) =  Fin 1`. So I further define

```
negate Fin x = Fin (0 - x)
```

But this gives error

```
? Equations for ‘negate’ have different numbers of arguments
```

How can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: `negate` is already defined by the `Num` class; any reason you aren't making a `Num Weight` instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need brackets for pattern matches:

```
negate (Fin x) = Fin (0 - x)
```

Otherwise, it looks like you've got two arguments.

This is reflected in the error: "Equations for ‘negate’ have **different numbers of arguments**".

This doesn't apply for `Inf`, because it takes no arguments.

Comment: Yeah, I tried `negate Fin x = 0 - x`. But this is obviously wrong.